# URL perfectly working on localhost, not working on web server

Tags: php, .htaccess

I've tried other solutions posted here, but nothing worked..

I have the following code on .htaccess doc.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^registrationForm/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ registrationForm.php?code=$1
RewriteRule ^registrationForm/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/$ registrationForm.php?code=$1
```

I receive an email and by clicking on the url I get access to registrationForm.php

I start registrationForm.php like that:

```
<?php
if (!empty($_GET['code']) && isset($_GET['code']))
{
    $code=$_GET['code'];
```

Do someone knows why this works on localhost but not on remote server?

Comment: The remote server is a webhost I think ? Did they accept URL rewriting ?

Comment: Do you get any error messages? What happens when you follow the url on your live server? Is `mod_rewrite enabled`?

Comment: it's a webhost, and I think they accept URL rewriting but I will research about that.

Sorry, send without answering maxhb. I get that:

404 Not Found

Not Found

The requested URL /registrationForm/83d33970e8fd0dea1b9d39b9ea4169f6 was not found on this server.

I dont know about mod_rewrite, where can I check?

Comment: Just use a really simple .htaccess and see if it works. E.g. `RewriteRule .* http://www.google.com` should redirect ever url to google. See if it works, can be tried in a subdirectory if you want to avoid redirecting all traffic of your webhost.

Comment: I checked and its enabled

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is not how you got the code running in acquiring the code. The problem could have occurred here.

```
if (!empty($_GET['code']) && isset($_GET['code']))
{
    $code=$_GET['code'];
```

The line of code above was not able to get the `code` part which is part of your querystring. The querystring that has been generated doesn't have the word `code` in it. You may want to read [this article](http://youhack.me/2010/04/01/building-a-registration-system-with-email-verification-in-php/).

Comment: I've read this article and modified my php file. Now it works and I understand it better!!!

I deleted .htaccess
The mail is built in such a way:

$body= $base_url . 'registrationForm.php?' .  "key=$activation";


Instead of 'code' now I use 'key'.