# URL perfectly working on localhost, not working on web server. Part II

Tags: php

The question follows a problem that I had, and I solved here:

[URL perfectly working on localhost, not working on web server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35058025/url-perfectly-working-on-localhost-not-working-on-web-server)

I receive an email and by clicking on the url I get access to registration.php

I start registration.php like that:

```
if (  ((isset($_GET['key'])) and (strlen($_GET['key']) == 32)) )

{
//FORM GOES HERE
}
else
{
header('Location: index.php');
}
```

In that way I get that only the people who click on the mail get the form.

At the beginning of the form I have:

```
if (session_status() == PHP_SESSION_NONE) {
session_start();
```

When I submit the form button, I save the variables in the $_SESSION superglobal.

If there are no errors, the next line follows:

```
header('Location: registrationValidation.php');
```

At the start of registrationValidation.php I have again

```
if (session_status() == PHP_SESSION_NONE) {
    session_start();
```

And if I click "back" button in registrationValidation.php, I go to registration.php.

It works perfectly in localhost, but I get error 500 on web server, and I cant get the error log files. Any idea?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: _"I cant get the error log files"_ Start by fixing this - you'll save yourself time in the long run.

Comment: Is there a reason you saved the data from form in session variables and redirect to validation page, instead of using `$_POST` and the `action` attribute of the form?

Comment: Surely you can access the error log in someway: take a look at provider documentation. what is your provider?

Comment: @yangsunny because I want to come back to the form and have the values posted

Comment: @JamesThorpe I cant access to the phpmyadmin now, where are found the error log files I guess.

In the browser I see:

Error 500: Cant find http://myDomain/mySite?424253452 on the server